# Do the four fundalmental forces of physics have a constant acceleration as gravity

Tags: forces

Do the four fundalmental forces of physics have a constant acceleration as gravity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. objects with different masses will often have the same electric charge--note the proton and the electron as examples of this.  Or even more tellingly, the electron and the muon.